# How to remove linebreaks in IE with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I am trying to remove linebreaks with JavaScript. It works in all browsers except Internet Explorer (tested in ie7, ie8). I have read a lot of posts but couldn't find a solution to the problem.

```
Var someText = "Here’s your text.\n It has line breaks that need to be removed.\rUsing Javascript.\r\n"; 

someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

What else can I try?

* EDITED ***********

Here's more code and a better explanation of my problem:

```
function checkLength(fn) {
    var fn = document.getElementById(fn);
    var fnb = fn.value;
    var fnb = fnb.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    var len = fnb.length;
    ...
```

What I am trying to do is calculate the number of chars in a textarea. I had to calculate with both Javascript and PHP and because of the linebreaks, PHP and Javascript never came to the same number. When removing the linebreaks, it is all good except in Internet Explorer (when I calculate it with Javascript). fnb.replace doesn't change anything in Internet Explorer for the character count so that is why I am sure it does not remove the linebreaks correctly. In all other browsers it is fine, I can see the difference in the counter after removing the linebreaks in javascript. Only in ie it doesn't change a thing. I have tried a couple of things as well as your suggestions below and the char count before removing the linebreaks and after is the same in ie.

///////// MY ANSWER /////////////////////////////////////

```
function checkLength(fn) {
    var fn = document.getElementById(fn);
    var fnb = fn.value;
    var fnb = fnb.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    var len = fnb.length;
...
```

Like Tomalak said, my logic could be improved - Sorry for being new to JavaScript & programming. Maybe Tomalak doesn't make any mistakes but I'm sure everyone else does. We have to make mistakes to learn.

Internet Explorer didn't like

```
var fn = document.getElementById(fn);
var fnb = fn.value;
```

I had to change it to:

```
var fnb = document.getElementById(fn).value;
```

Even if it wasn't logical, it should have worked. It did work in all browsers except ie. It's a bug.

That was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You're focusing too much on trying to find completely different things to "try", instead of trying to work out why your current code is causing an error (and I can only assume that you're getting an error, because you haven't really told us what _is_ happening). In fact, other than the issue with `Var` that I discuss in my answer, [the code is fine](http://tom.kera.name/lol.html) so you need to be looking at what you already have in other areas of your code and figuring out what you've done wrong.

Comment: This isn't the problem you're asking about, but this regex is simpler: `/\r|\n/gm`.

Comment: @Toamalak : I updated my post and you have more details now. Sorry for not being a pro man.. I wish I could be but I gotta start somewhere.

Comment: @Mathiew: You don't have to be a "pro" at Javascript to think logically through a problem. It's a general life skill. :) And I can't really parse that edit; it's just a big wall of text to me. I think you're going to have to come back when you have a testcase and a specific question and a specific, narrowed-down piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
someText = someText.replace(/[\r\n]+/gm,"");
```

Comment: How does this differ, functionally, from the original? Why is the original broken in IE?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the regular expression works just fine in at least IE8.0.

The real problem is that you wrote `Var` instead of `var`; Firefox lets you get away with it, but IE doesn't.

Comment: @Mathiew: It works just fine for me. You must have done something else wrong. Time to bust out the developer console and get an actual error message. (Actually it was time to do that the _moment_ you got a problem!)

Comment: @Mathiew: Check for me that http://tom.kera.name/lol.html "doesn't work" for you in IE8.

Comment: You're right. It does work this way. I'll edit my post and show more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the m flag, but you ought to replace with a space instead of nothing.

```
someText = someText.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,' ');
```